# JS callback returns undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, callback, socket.io

I thought I knew how to achieve a callback, here is what I have:

index.html:

```
socket.on('userCapture', data, function(callback){
    if(callback){
        //do stuff
    } else {
        alert('Username in use.');
    }
});
```

index.js:

```
socket.on('userCapture', function(data, callback){
    username = data.username;
    question = data.question;
    socket.username = username;
    socket.room = username;

    function isInArray(arr,obj) {
        return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
    }
    if(isInArray(usernames, username)){
        callback(false);
    } else {
        callback(true);
    }
});
```

The idea is I check the usernames array for the value passed and pass back to the client if it exists or not.. I dont understand why it is resulting in undefined as I have the exact same code elsewhere and it works..

Regards

Comment: where is `index.js` located? is it server-side?

Comment: Yes, I am using nodejs with socket.io

Comment: how are you sending the `callback`? You can't actually send functions through a websocket.

Comment: as a function.. how do you mean..? Are you certain as I have another for login.. socket.emit('login', data, function(login){}); this works fine..

Comment: the problem is you're trying to this with `socket.on`, you can only specify a callback when you `emit` a message.

Comment: Sosdoc, thankyou! You were correct! I have it working on emit now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying a callback for `socket.on()`, you can't do that.
Callbacks are possible with `emit()` or `send()` as per the [Socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements)), since you want to basically send a message and then retrieve the result without writing a different `socket.on()`.

Change your code to use `emit()`

**Client code**

```
socket.emit('userCapture', data, function(response){
    if(response){
        //do stuff
    } else {
        alert('Username in use.');
    }
});
```

**Server code**

```
socket.on('userCapture', function(data, callback){
    username = data.username;
    question = data.question;
    socket.username = username;
    socket.room = username;

    function isInArray(arr,obj) {
        return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
    }

    // you can just send the result back
    callback(isInArray(usernames, username));
});
```